# Disable stacktraces in Tomcat's error pages to make it ready for production

Tags: security, tomcat

I am running a Tomcat on AWS. The problem is that when a request crashes with an exception, Tomcat not only sends the 503, but also sends the exception's stack trace in HTML. This exposes my source code to a viewer who doesn't need to see it.

How do I disable this?

Answer (score 14):

The error page is generated by a simple error handler, the [Error Report Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve). You can hide stack traces (`showReport`) as well as the server info by adding these lines to your `server.xml`'s `Host` section:

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
    showReport="false" 
    showServerInfo="false" />
```

Another solution is to use custom, user friendly [error pages for every HTTP error code](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q6):

```xml
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

as well as for every different `Throwable`:

```xml
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/error-Exception.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.sql.SQLException</exception-type>
    <location>/error-SQLException.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: I looked through server.xml, but it has no ErrorReportValve. Is this valve added implicitly, and I need to explicitly set it to don't showReport?

Comment: `server.xml` doesn't initially include all the possible executors, connectors, containers, components, elements and their possible combinations from the [Tomcat Config Reference](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/).